# pass a reference to 'this' in the constructor

Tags: c#, constructor

I know I have done this before but I am getting my constructor order of execution in a twist I think....

```
public class Class1
{
    Class2 _class2;

    public Class1()
    {
        _class2 = new Class2(this);
    }
}

public class Class2 
{
    Class1 _parent; //corrected typo

    public Class2(Class1 parent)
    {
        _parent = parent;
    }
}
```

trouble is that parent always ends up null.

What's the proper way to do this? (maybe I can blame my slowness on having a cold..)

EDITED TO CORRECT THE TYPO (which isn't the problem in the real code!)

Comment: do you perhaps mean "Class1 _parent;" instead of "Class1 parent;"?

Comment: I had a comment on a deleted answer, so I will throw in my 2 cents here. You're treading on dangerous turf.  Since the Class1 instance isn't fully constructed, the Class2 constructor can do some very bad things... imagine this in the Class2 constructor: parent.Child = this; // yikes

Comment: "Works on my machine".  However I agree with Michael, using this during construction is a smell to be avoided.

Comment: I also agree it's horrible - have gone for lazy intialisation as suggested (and as I have done before).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should, technically, work, provided you change Class2 to include `this.parent = parent;`

However, I don't recommend this.  I would, instead, recommend lazy initializing your class2 instance inside class1.  Depending on what all is done in the constructor of Class2, you can potentially lead yourself into nasty situations.

Making a Class2 property on class1 and lazy initializing it would cause Class2 to be constructed after Class1's constructor is completed, not during it's construction, which is most likely less error prone if your classes get more complicated.

Comment: in the production code it is a property. thanks - thhis is how I havne it in the past....

Comment: oh my - I really cannot type today, can I :-)

Answer (score 10):

You may have mistyped the code, but I think you want this definition for Class2 (notice the *this* qualifier in your Class2 constructor):

```
public class Class2 
{
    Class1 parent;

    public Class2(Class1 parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: If it were as simple as a typo its not likely to compile.

Answer (score 2):

```
Class1 parent;
_parent = parent;
```

_parent is never defined; you misspelled it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I thought I'd throw my two cents in for good measure. Google brought me here so it may bring someone else here.

This suspiciously looks like a circular dependency... it's quite the code smell to have two independent classes that use/reference each other.

If you want to have a parent/child relationship for objects, consider making a binary tree implementation (or similar) for your class.

If you want to exploit class inheritance, use it correctly >
`Class2` is a base class for `Class1` and your `Class1` declaration would be `public class Class1 : Class2`. You can refer to `Class2`'s methods in `Class1` with the `base` keyword.

So in short, this answer is: you need to redesign your classes to better fit what you're trying to accomplish, rather than fight the compiler to do something that's more confusing than it needs to be.

Especially since the code you're going to be testing this with is probably newing up `Class1`, then querying that object for its reference to `Class2`'s reference for `Class1`... which is absolutely pointless.

Append2:

Semantically, `Class1` can be rewritten as follows:

```
public class Class1
{
    Class2 _class2;

    public Class1()
        :this(new Class2(this))
    {
    }
    public Class1(Class2 class2)
    {
        _class2 = class2;
    }
}
```

... except it can't, because `:this(new Class2(this))` is rightfully incorrect syntax. It's also exactly what you're doing. Please don't.

Comment: And as a side note: I'm here because someone's implemented a large amount of classes using this pattern and it's incredibly annoying to unwind into something less annoying. PLEASE don't use OP's pattern if you're reading this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this shouldn't work. It works with me.

declared:
http://vvcap.net/db/I2OZoapbIRREvQ8ymPym.htp

stepped over:
http://vvcap.net/db/ehsYqCY6JByqZQq-RXGp.htp

here's the result:
http://vvcap.net/db/ZWjqb_Yv1yAisX0BYUns.htp

Comment: Links are broken.